# Freemarker - Is there a way to format an integer as a floating point number?

Tags: java, freemarker

That's pretty much the question. I just want to do something basic like

```
5
```

and format it as

```
5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

```
${myNumber?string(",##0.0")}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Note that according to the documentation https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number formatting is locale specific, so you might get `5,0` instead of `5.0` in ru_RU locale. To avoid this, you might specify decimal separator like so: `${myNumber?string(",##0.0;; decimalSeparator='.'")}`